# Appending parameters in Python

Tags: python, web.py

I would like to use a for loop to create something like this:

```
my_form = form.Form(
    form.Button("btn", id="btn0", value = "0", html="One!", class_="btnZero")
     form.Button("btn", id="btn1", value = "1", html="Two!", class_="btnOne")
    form.Button("btn", id="btn2", value = "2", html="Three!", class_="btnThree")
)
```

How could I achieve this? Each time it loops round, it has to create a form.button inside of my_form and form.Form(), each with different parameters. So like one has a value of 0, another 1, another 2, etc. And the HTML being the same.

Comment: Are the three `form.Button` objects three different arguments to `form.Form`? If they are, then you are missing the commas needed to separate them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
lst = ['Zero','One','Two','Three']
for i in range(3):
    form.Button("btn", id="btn"+str(i), value = str(i), html=lst[i+1]+'!', class_="btn"+str(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html = lst = ['Zero','One','Two','Three']
my_form = form.Form(*[form.Button("btn", id="btn" + str(i), value = i, html=html[i], class_="btn" +str(i)) for i in range(3)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
counter = ['Zero','One','Two','Three']
my_form = form.Form(*[form.Button("btn", id="btn{}".format(i), value=str(i), html="{}!".format(counter[i+1]), class="_btn{}".format(counter[i]) for i in range(3)])
```